# Tensorflow2.4 resume training with custom training loop and mirror strategy

Tags: keras, tf.keras, tensorflow2.x

I'm Training a model with a [distributed strategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy) and a [custom Training Loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch),I  save the model at the end of the training using:

`model.save('net',save_format='tf')`

My question is after i load the model using :

```
re_load_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("net", compile=False)
```

[here is a notebook as a references](https://github.com/innat/TensorFlow-2-Practice/blob/main/Custom_Loop_Training_InceptionNet.ipynb)

How I can resume training? any idea please!

Thanks